# Retrieve specific element of a nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Just cannot figure this out. This is the document format from a MongoDB of jobs, which is derived from an XML file the layout of which I have no control over:

```
{
    "reference" : [ "93417" ],
    "Title" : [ "RN - Pediatric Director of Nursing" ],
    "Description" : [ "...a paragraph or two..." ],
    "Classifications" : [ 
        {
            "Classification" : [ 
                {
                    "_" : "Nurse / Midwife",
                    "name" : [ "Category" ]
                }, 
                {
                    "_" : "FL - Jacksonville",
                    "name" : [ "Location" ],
                }, 
                {
                    "_" : "Permanent / Full Time",
                    "name" : [ "Work Type" ],
                }, 
                {
                    "_" : "Some Health Care Org",
                    "name" : [ "Company Name" ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Apply" : [ 
        {
            "EmailTo" : [ "jess@recruiting.co" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The intention is to pull a list of jobs from the DB, to include 'Location', which is buried down there as the second document at 'Classifications.Classification._'.

I've tried various 'aggregate' permutations of $project, $unwind, $match, $filter, $group… but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Experimenting with just retrieving the company name, I was expecting this to work:

```
db.collection(JOBS_COLLECTION).aggregate([
    { "$project" : { "meta": "$Classifications.Classification" } },
    { "$project" : { "meta": 1, _id: 0 } },
    { "$unwind" : "$meta" },
    { "$match": { "meta.name" : "Company Name" } },
    { "$project" : { "Company" : "$meta._" } },
])
```

But that pulled everything for every record, thus:

```
[{
    "Company":[
        "Nurse / Midwife",
        "TX - San Antonio",
        "Permanent / Full Time",
        "Some Health Care Org"
    ]
}, { etc etc }]
```

What am I missing, or misusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally with MongoDB 3.4 available you would simply [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), and use the array operators of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/). The latter to "compact" the arrays and the former to to extract the relevant element and detail. Also [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) takes just the "element" from the array(s):

```
db.collection(JOBS_COLLECTION).aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Classifications.Classification.name": "Location" } },
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "output": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$Classifications.Classification",
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]    
                  }
                }
              },
              "as": "c",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$c.name", ["Location"] ] }        
            }
          },
          "as": "c",
          "in": "$$c._"
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Or even skip the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) which is merely applying the [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to "merge" and simply grab the "first" array index ( since there is only **one** ) using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/):

```
db.collection(JOBS_COLLECTION).aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Classifications.Classification.name": "Location" } },
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "output": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$Classifications.Classification", 0 ] },
              "as": "c",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$c.name", ["Location"] ] }        
            }
          },
          "as": "c",
          "in": "$$c._"
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

That makes the operation compatible with MongoDB 3.2, which you "should" be running at least.

Which in turn allows you to consider alternate syntax for MongoDB 3.4 using [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) based on the initial input variable of the "first" array index using [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to somewhat shorten the syntax:

```
db.collection(JOBS_COLLECTION).aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Classifications.Classification.name": "Location" } },
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "output": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "meta": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$Classifications.Classification",
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$$meta._",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ 
              "$$meta.name", [ "Location" ]
            ]}  
          ]     
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

If indeed you consider that to be "shorter", that is.

---

In the other sense though, much like above there is an "array inside and array", so in order to process it, you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) **twice**, which is effectively what the [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) inside [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) is countering in the ideal case:

```
db.collection(JOBS_COLLECTION).aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Classifications.Classification.name": "Location" } },
  { "$unwind": "$Classifications" },
  { "$unwind": "$Classifications.Classification" },
  { "$match": { "Classifications.Classification.name": "Location" } },
  { "$project": { "_id": 0, "output": "$Classifications.Classification._" } }
])
```

All statements actually produce:

```
{
    "output" : "FL - Jacksonville"
}
```

Which is the matching value of `"_"` in the inner array element for the `"Location"` as selected by your original intent.

Keeping in mind of course that **all** statements really should be preceded with the relevant `[$match`][9](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) statement as shown:

```
{ "$match": { "Classifications.Classification.name": "Location" } },
```

Since without that you would be possibly processing documents unnecessarily, which did not actually contain an array element matching that condition. Of course this may not be the case due to the nature of the documents, but it's generally good practice to make sure the "initial" selection always matches the conditions of details you later intend to "extract".

All of that said, even if this is the result of a direct import from XML, the structure should be changed since it does not efficiently present itself for queries. MongoDB documents do not work how XPATH does in terms of issuing queries. Therefore anything "XML Like" is not going to be a good structure, and if the "import" process cannot be changed to a more accommodating format, then there should at least be a "post process" to manipulate this into a separate storage in a more usable form.

Comment: Neil, your last example is so simple it leaves me somewhat embarrassed — but elated. Many thanks! I shall, nonetheless, explore your other examples for a deeper insight.

Comment: So, how would this solution be applicable — or have to be modified — to retrieve multiple nested fields, e.g. "Location", "Work Type", "Company Name", 'in the same breath' so to speak? It's not a case of cascading "$match" operators, because then you'd need an "$un-unwind" operator.

Comment: @Tycho That would be a different question, for which you should [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead and make your intentions clear. The answer here is actually saying to "preferably" not use `$unwind` at all. The other options are way better performance wise, and `$unwind` really should not be used for any other purpose than actually using a resulting value for a "grouping key" in any modern version. New operators for dealing with arrays are specifically introduced for the point of **not** using `$unwind`.

Comment: Thank you for that. Also, I had wondered about relative performance, glad you brought that up.